# No result from pgRoutingLayer tsp(euclid) algorithm

Tags: qgis-plugins, pgrouting

I use QGIS plugin pgRoutingLayer for displaying the shortest route. Dijkstra algorithm works fine.

I tried tsp (euclid) algorithm but it drew nothing (even no error message). I thought it may be something wrong with my data. So I uploaded pgRouting sample data into my database (http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/doc/src/developer/sampledata.html) and tried tsp on them. But result was the same (no route and no error message).

So I debugged the pgRoutingLayer plugin, caught the sql query. It looks like this and it results in 0 records

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS internal, id2 AS node, cost FROM pgr_tsp('
               SELECT DISTINCT id, x, y FROM
                   (SELECT DISTINCT source AS id, x1::float8 AS x, y1::float8 AS y FROM edge_table
                   UNION
                   SELECT DISTINCT target AS id, x2::float8 AS x, y2::float8 AS y FROM edge_table)
                   AS node WHERE node.id IN (7,8,11)',
               2, 12)
```

I may be missing some basics, I am a routing newbie. Can anyone give me a hand please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include "source_id" and "target_id" values in "ids" value.
So, could you try to change "ids" value from "7,8,11" to "2,7,8,11,12"?

I will try to think about reporting error message in this case.

Comment: I tried that. But when I included those values query ended with this error: "Error: matrix[num][num] in its definition".

Comment: Okay. Then I will try to test it with the sample data.

Comment: After I reinstalled database the matrix error dissapeared. So including target and source into the set is the right way. Thanks